# Express port is undefined when running with "node ."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I've been following the tutorial here and it's been fine up until the part where I had to run the server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript

If I try and run the code below I get `server is listening on undefined`

```
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})

app.listen((port, err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

I even tried to set the port beforehand using `app.set('port', port);`

```
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.set('port', port);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})

app.listen((port, err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

But the same thing happens.

Answer (score 8):

`app.listen` accept **two arguments**, first one is port, second is callback.
Change it to following code.

```js
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

This is an example in tutorial. He ignores the `()` in function from `(err) => {}` to `err => {}`, both work.

```js
app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. This works now thanks. Looks like that tutorial needs updated.

Comment: @jm123456 If this answer helped you, you can click the tick next to it to accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

this is wrong, because `app.listen()` does not take "err". Its callback does not take any argument. If you were using typescript, you would get warning. If `app.listen()` gets an error, it will not run and client will get 404 error. it is just like this:

```
 app.listen(port,()=>{
     console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)})
```

Answer (score -1):

change it with following code , first params will be port

```js
app.listen(port, err) => {
    if (err)return console.error(err);
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: this does not compile, could you improve it?